# I can't get my boolean type method to return correctly

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to write a program that takes three sides of a triangle in any order, re arranges them in ascending order (a,b,c) and then tells the user what type of triangle it is and the area. However I can't figure out what is wrong with my code that it keeps getting the wrong true/false value for my isValid method. Even if the sides don't make up a triangle it still proceeds as if the isValid method had returned true. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {                                   

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter three numbers:");
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        double b = input.nextDouble();
        double c = input.nextDouble();

        if (a > b)
        {
            double temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        if (b > c)
        {
            double temp = b;
            b = c;
            c = temp;
        }
        if (a > b)
        {
            double temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }

        double area = area(a, b, c);
        boolean isValid = isValid(a, b, c);
        String type = type(a, b, c);

        if (isValid = true)
        {
            System.out.println("This triangle is " + type);
            System.out.printf("The area is %.2f", area, "\n\n");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid triangle");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        if (a + b > c)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static double area(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        double s = (a + b + c)/2.0;
        double area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
        return area;
    }

    public static String type(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        String type;

        if (a == c)
        {
            type = "equilateral";
        } else if (a == b || b == c)
        {
            type = "isosceles";
        } else 
        {
            type = "scalene";
        }
        return type;          
    }
}
```

Comment: What are some inputs that work incorrectly? Also, you can just say `return (a + b) > c;` instead of repeating yourself.

Comment: If I do 12, 6, 5 or the reverse order it comes up with "The triangle is scalene The area is NaN" both times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be here (unless it was a typo):

```
if (isValid = true)
```

You're assigning `true` to `isValid`, so the condition in the `if` statement is *always* true.

The proper way to do comparison of primitive values is by using two equals signs:

```
if (isValid == true)
```

However, for booleans, this is redundant. The best way to test if a boolean value is true/false is simply to use the boolean variable itself:

```
if (isValid)
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks for catching that. Been looking at this way too long and I doubt I would have seen it any time soon. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Just to let you know, in some IDEs (I know it's there for Eclipse at least), there's an option to turn on compiler warnings for possible accidental assignments in conditions. That could help protect against future mistakes